# Storing trees with parent and child pointers in Raven

Tags: c#, json.net, ravendb

I have a tree structure in which the nodes have both child pointers and a parent pointer. I'm having some problems getting this to serialize nicely (this will be used for configuration, so it needs to be somewhat readable to operations/configuration managers), and after experimenting with different combinations of serialization conventions and attributes I'm still stuck.

My types look like this:

```
public class NestedConfigurationTree<T> where T : class
{
    public InternalNode<T> _root { get; set; }

    public class InternalNode<TValue> where TValue : class
    {
        public Dictionary<string, InternalNode<TValue>> _children { get; set; }
        public InternalNode<TValue> _parent  { get; set; }
        public TValue _value  { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I allow circular references (`[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]`), each node gets JSON looking like this:

```
        "$id": "3",
        "_children": {
          "ConfigurationItem": {
            "$id": "4",
            "_children": {},
            "_parent": {
              "$ref": "3"
            },
            "_value": "Some value"
          }
        },
```

This apparently confuses the end users, and they don't want the $id and _parent stuff. Since the parent is quite obvious from the document structure, can I avoid serializing it and somehow recreate it when loading?

Also, is it possible to avoid having public properties? I originally wrote it as `private readonly` fields, but that made the serializer ignore all of them.

Comment: Why are your end users looking at the raw JSON?

Comment: @AyendeRahien: It's for a configuration management tool, and it is a requirement that the raw data should be "readily editable in the database management tool". Basically, if the tool breaks, they want to be able to go into the database and change settings.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything is suitable to store directly in a database.  You've shown a great example of such a scenario.  If your end-users would be confused by it, then so would any queries you'd want to write against it.

My recommendation would be to have a version of the tree that does not have these references.  Serialized, looking like such:

```
{
  "Value" : "A",
  "Children" : [
    {
      "Value" : "B",
      "Children" : [
        {
          "Value" : "C",
          "Children" : [
            {
                "Value" : "D",
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Value" : "E",
          "Children" : [
            {
                "Value" : "F",
                "Children" : []
            },
            {
                "Value" : "G",
                "Children" : []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When serializing, you would just ignore the parent/child links and when deserializing you would wire them back up.

Instead of a second set of classes, you could do this all in a custom `JsonConverter` - which gives you fine-grained control over how to serialize or deserialize any particular entity.

Another option (and maybe the simplest) would be to use methods instead of properties for traversal links.  In other words, instead of:

```
Node Parent { get; }
IEnumerable<Node> Children { get; }
```

You would use:

```
Node GetParent();
IEnumerable<Node> GetChildren();
```

Methods don't get followed during serialization, so this can be the easiest thing to do.